# Anonymous can create content while permission isn't given

Tags: drupal, permissions, anonymous

I'm running a blog with Drupal 6 and I have a problem.

Anonmymous user see a "Create Content" option under a "Navigation" menu although they don't have permission create content. 
I've checked in the "permissions" table in the DB and everything looks fine.

The problem occured after I gave the permission, to test something, and removed it after. Since then, the menu is there and I can't remove it.

Let me know if you need more info.

Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm...I'm not able to reproduce this.  What other modules do you have enabled that might work with permissions?  Another possibility might be to rebuild permissions on admin/content/node-settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found a solution:**

Go to Admin-> Site Building-> Blocks-> Navigation

Choose "Show if the following PHP code returns TRUE" and use the following code:

```
<?php
global $user;
return ($user->uid > 0);
?>
```

Comment: I don't think he's trying to hide the entire block... just the "Create Content" link.

Answer (score 0):

And did you clear the menu cache after changing the permissions?

Comment: If you mean Admin>Site Configuration>Performance>Clear Cached Data, yes I did